# Why does my icons in VSTO Addins looks blurry?

Tags: .net, vsto, office-addins

I am building a VSTO add-in and used icons with sizes mostly 80x80 or 100x100, but when I open the Excel in 27-inch monitor. The icons are very blurry as shown. Can someone help me with how to correct this?

[image]

[image]

Backend code

```
<ribbon>
        <tabs>
          <tab id="tab2" label="AuxBits Tools">
            <group id="grpSheet" label="Worksheet" getImage="GetImage">
              <button id="btnNavigation" onAction="btnNavigation_Click" label="Easy Navigation" size="large" getImage="GetImage" />
              <separator id="separator" />
              <button id="btnTOC" onAction="btnTOC_Click" label="Insert Table of Contents" size="large" getImage="GetImage" />
              <button id="btnProtect" onAction="btnProtect_Click" label="Protect Sheets" size="large" getImage="GetImage" />



public Bitmap GetImage(IRibbonControl control)
        {
            switch (control.Id)
            {
                case "grpSheet":
                    return new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.GrpWorksheet);
                case "btnNavigation":
                    return new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.navigation);
```

Comment: Does the OS have a non 100% scaling factor?

Comment: how does it matter? he native ribbon icons looks sharper and crisp

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office applications scale images according to the DPI value if PNG and BMP files are used. In case of ICO files, an appropriate resolution of the image can be picked up by Office, so you can embed different sizes of the single image to an ICO file.

For any image, the exact pixel size is dependent on the display resolution, or dots per inch (dpi), of the monitor being used. At 96 dpi, large images are 32x32 pixels in size and small images are 16x16 pixels in size. The image sizes increase in a linear fashion relative to dpi. Most ribbon controls in Office will require both 32×32 and 16×16 pixel icons (only 16×16 icons are used by the Quick Access Toolbar). Ribbon galleries typically use 16×16, 32×32, 48×48, or 64×64 pixel icons.

The Ribbon UI scales image resources as required. However, because resizing may yield undesirable artifacts and image degradation, it is highly recommended that the application provide a small set of image resources that span various commonly used dpi settings. If an exact match is not found, the nearest image will be scaled up or down. The `getImage` callback may help to retrieve the best-suited according to the DPI value set.

Comment: are you recommending using a .ico file instead of .png? I have updated my backend code on how I am assigning the images. Please let me know

Comment: You are free to use BMP, but I'd recommend checking the DPI value and return an appropriate image size.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get that.. can you give some examples in VSTO

Comment: VSTO doesn't provide anything for that. You just need to check the OS DPI value and then return in the callback an appropriate image.